# FFmpeg scale and concat with dynamic height

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi below is the code I'm using to concat multiple images.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 1 -i img1.jpeg -loop 1 -t 1 -i img2.jpeg -loop 1 -t 1 -i img3.jpeg 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i img4.jpeg -filter_complex "
[0:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];
[1:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v1];
[2:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v2];
[3:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v3];
[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4"  output.gif
```

But I'm getting below issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each pad, add setsar,

e.g.

```
[0:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v0];
```

Other method is to allow unsafe concat, but this is not recommended.

```
[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:unsafe=1
```

Comment: Working fine. Thanks

Comment: Gyan with balck padding I got output like https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y55l.gif
But with transparent padding I got output like https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnhFb.gif. Is there any way to fix this

Comment: Share full log. Can't reproduce this.